Resource not found error on Assets Listing Page
I'm encountering the following error as Resource not found on the Assets Listing page in Sitecore Content hub while doing a full-text search. Does anybody have any idea what is causing this error or how to Troubleshoot it? It is not creating any issues in the normal functionalities of the listing page

I got the similar issue on one of my project, where it was related to access on the FullTextQueryConfiguration settings under the SearchConfiguration category for the user role.
In order to resolve this issue, you can configure access to them as below.

Provide access to the SearchConfiguration category, by configuring the read access as below.



Provide access to the FullTextQueryConfiguration setting, by configuring the
read access as below.


Using above way, user role will have access to this setting and the 404 issue regarding Resource not found issue would be resolved.
Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you face any issues.

Thank you, the information provided helped me in resolving the issue

Glad to hear that @girishjain!!!
